# Performing multiple queries in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I am performing a query in yii2 which requires two conditions . I have tried"

```
$query = Evidence::find()
->where(['case_ref'=>$id && 'evidence_type'="picture"]);
$dataProviderb = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

But I keep on getting error of unexpected = and expecting ]. How can I perform multiple queries in yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always recommend use [GII](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html)'s crud generator after creating a model (or even generating by **GII**) and, after that, made your adjusts and delete what you not going to use.

Since i can't find a example of the search in the docs, here is a sample:

```
$query = Evidence::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['case_ref' => $id])
    ->andFilterWhere(['evidence_type' => 'picture']);

$dataProviderb = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Not sure where you calling this... usually you have a modelSearch that already loaded input from get parameters. So instead of `$id` you should probably use `$this->id`. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Here is more info about **ActiveQueryInterface** (what is generated by `find()` method): http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface.html